# Notification from subscription does not notify specific domains

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are migrating from one pre-production platform on the cloud to another server. We have successfully migrated everything but something strange is happening with the subscriptions of Orion Context Broker, since our instance of Orion is successfully notifying different endpoints, but not the one from our platform.

Both of the subscriptions are done from the same instance and implementing HTTPS, and the security groups are equally configured. The Orion context broker logs doesnt show any useful information about what is happening with the cURL request that internally is doing.

Here is an example of a right subscription from this Orion:

```
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.102Z | lvl=INFO | corr=e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000009 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction from 54.194.53.34:48920/v1/updateContext
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.102Z | lvl=INFO | corr=e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000009 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=pending | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[882]:servicePathSplit | msg=Service Path 0: '/howto'
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.103Z | lvl=INFO | corr=e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000009 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[92]:collectionQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "M1111", _id.type: "Thing", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/howto$/ ] } })
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.104Z | lvl=INFO | corr=e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000009 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[447]:collectionUpdate | msg=Database Operation Successful (update: <{ _id.id: "M1111", _id.type: "Thing", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/howto$/ ] } }, { $set: { attrs.local: { value: "1.1.1.1,50", type: "string", md: { TimeInstant: { type: "ISO8601", value: "2017-11-14T12:54:03.090Z" } }, mdNames: [ "TimeInstant" ], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664043 }, attrs.serial_number: { value: "M1111", type: "string", md: { TimeInstant: { type: "ISO8601", value: "2017-11-14T12:54:03.090Z" } }, mdNames: [ "TimeInstant" ], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664043 }, attrs.TimeInstant: { value: "2017-11-14T12:54:03.090Z", type: "ISO8601", mdNames: [], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664043 }, modDate: 1510664043, lastCorrelator: "e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003" }, $unset: { location: 1 } }>)
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.104Z | lvl=INFO | corr=e42533b2-c93a-11e7-b333-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000009 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.105Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000010 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction to https://visualfy.secmotic.com:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.105Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000010 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[599]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Sending message 2 to HTTP server: sending message of 540 bytes to HTTP server
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.238Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000010 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[620]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification Successfully Sent to https://visualfy.secmotic.com:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:54:03 2017.239Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000010 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
```

And here is an example of a failed notification.

```
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.809Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000012 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction from 54.194.53.34:48922/v1/updateContext
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.810Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000012 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=pending | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[882]:servicePathSplit | msg=Service Path 0: '/howto'
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.810Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000012 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[92]:collectionQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "M1111", _id.type: "Thing", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/howto$/ ] } })
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.811Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000012 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[447]:collectionUpdate | msg=Database Operation Successful (update: <{ _id.id: "M1111", _id.type: "Thing", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/howto$/ ] } }, { $set: { attrs.local: { value: "1.1.1.1,50", type: "string", md: { TimeInstant: { type: "ISO8601", value: "2017-11-14T12:55:13.800Z" } }, mdNames: [ "TimeInstant" ], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664113 }, attrs.serial_number: { value: "M1111", type: "string", md: { TimeInstant: { type: "ISO8601", value: "2017-11-14T12:55:13.800Z" } }, mdNames: [ "TimeInstant" ], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664113 }, attrs.TimeInstant: { value: "2017-11-14T12:55:13.800Z", type: "ISO8601", mdNames: [], creDate: 1510662361, modDate: 1510664113 }, modDate: 1510664113, lastCorrelator: "0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003" }, $unset: { location: 1 } }>)
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.812Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0e4a4e20-c93b-11e7-957f-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000012 | from=54.194.53.34 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.812Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000013 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction to https://iot.visualfy.com:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.812Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000013 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[599]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Sending message 3 to HTTP server: sending message of 535 bytes to HTTP server
time=Tuesday 14 Nov 12:55:13 2017.891Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000013 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
```

The subscription is the same with the http attribute changed to the endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated and if you need further information don't hesitate asking.

**UPDATE 1**

After shutting down the process in the 443 port and adding a listener, performing a netcat like: `nc -l 443` has resulted in a notification arriving to netcat with a non readable data stream.
The orion context broker logs shows some interesting information:

```
    time=Friday 17 Nov 11:05:56 2017.587Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000090 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction to https://34.240.0.113:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:05:56 2017.587Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000090 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[599]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Sending message 22 to HTTP server: sending message of 531 bytes to HTTP server
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:06:04 2017.153Z | lvl=INFO | corr=4da159ee-cb87-11e7-97f4-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000091 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction from 37.11.95.120:60933/v2/subscriptions
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:06:04 2017.154Z | lvl=INFO | corr=4da159ee-cb87-11e7-97f4-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000091 | from=37.11.95.120 | srv=pending | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[882]:servicePathSplit | msg=Service Path 0: '/howto'
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:06:04 2017.154Z | lvl=INFO | corr=4da159ee-cb87-11e7-97f4-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000091 | from=37.11.95.120 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[175]:collectionRangedQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { query: { servicePath: "/howto" }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:06:04 2017.155Z | lvl=INFO | corr=4da159ee-cb87-11e7-97f4-0242ac110003 | trans=1510663280-019-00000000091 | from=37.11.95.120 | srv=howtoservice | subsrv=/howto | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
time=Friday 17 Nov 11:06:04 2017.556Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=1510663280-019-00000000090 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=AlarmManager.cpp[328]:notificationError | msg=Raising alarm NotificationError https://34.240.0.113:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local: (curl_easy_perform failed: SSL connect error)
```

Which has the same looking than the failed notification instead of the one that ended OK.

The same process to the service that is working, when the notification reachs netcat has more characters notifying. In other words, this is what I receive in the netcat that doesnt receive notifications correctly:

```
HD?#

    ?\?s???s0?^0M
                 c1\6?QSb?J3298/5
?
```

And this is what I receive in the netcat that receive the notifications OK:

```
?_????=?)>B??w??{?d?O?އ?$V? ?bG??B?>?????
                                         ????O???[06?gZZ̨̩?+?/?,?0????/5
? ?&???ualfy.secmotic.com#?ۻ????f??s??? ir????b???;?!~?"-$?}?G?A?Ӎ8????ؽV???%2ߨ??B&?
       ?Wr?n?<=T?h?A{R?Ϛ?y??'L1??1??????w"m?kY?oKl??5??%'?["?X9??h?f?`???Hj?%mZ?{???I?ʤx??v???m??H?9?????Ƥf%
hhttp/1.1uP


????@^C
```

**UPDATE 2**
It is clear now that it is an HTTPS error with the notifications.
I have gone in the docker container where Orion Context Broker is and tried to perform a curl to the HTTPS domain, having the following output:

```
* About to connect() to iot.visualfy.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 34.240.0.113... connected
* Connected to iot.visualfy.com (34.240.0.113) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I actually tried to configure Orion as the documentation says with the -insecureNotif option, but the result is the same.

Comment: In the case of failure you should have a message in the logs reporting that. Maybe the connection doesn't close and hangs so you are not getting it?

Comment: In any way, I'd recommend to do a connectivity smoke test. I mean, use curl or another similar tool to contact your remote endpoint from the host where Orion is running. Maybe the result of such test could help to know which is happening.

Comment: Another possible cause of failure could be certificates in HTTPS. Maybe your original endpoint accept Orion certificate, but the new one is not accepting.

Comment: Hi @fgalan
He have done the smoke tests previously to the question, and the system is accepting the expected curl request with the notification that orion should perform, and no cert is provided in this request, so I would discard those suggestions
If you have some more tests in mind that would help finding the issue, I would appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: Idea for test: shutdown your process at 443, put a `nc -l` listener in the same port (443) and try with an HTTP notification. If the result is ok, then the problem seems isolated to HTTPS notifications.

Comment: I did that test, and the transaction ended OK. So this would discard an error with the context broker?
Im editting the question with the log trace

Comment: I guess `(curl_easy_perform failed: SSL connect error)` is due to `nc` doesn't have true HTTPS decoding capabilities. However, the test shows that the notification (or at least part of it) arrives... Have you tried to change to HTTP notification in the same scenario?

Comment: We are going to test it via HTTP. I will come back with the results :)

Comment: We have tested without HTTPS and it notifies correctly. Nevertheless our platform has a valid and trustable certificate (letsencrypt certificate). Any hints about this?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not Orion acepting your server certificate as valid, but the other way around. Current Orion version uses the default certificate in its host (I think is the one that comes with openssh packages) and maybe your server is not accepting it as valid. Is there any log trace in your server about the connection attemp from Orion that could help to know what the problem is?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no trace in nginx about the notifications.

I'm running orion in a docker container. Would be the solution to install orion in a native centos 6.3 without docker?

Comment: I managed to import the certificates and the server key (fullchain.pem and cert.pem) into the docker container and use the options -key and -cert using the files from the container, but the result is always the same, and there is no trace in the logs of the server

Comment: Docker network is sometimes tricky... maybe it could be related with the cause of the problem. Installing Orion natively is pretty easy, just use yum or rpm command. The procedure is detailed in Orion aministration manual at: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/install/index.html

Comment: Okey, I will try to do this! Thanks

Comment: With regardso to fullchain.pem and cert.pem... you mean the keys used by your service listening at https://...:443/api/v1/devices/orion/local ?

Comment: Exactly @fgalan, the certs of that server

Comment: In that case, using them in -key and -cert will not help. The -key and -cert parameters set the certificate to be used in the *API server* by Orion, not for authenticate remote server when sending notifications.

Comment: I just installed orion from sources as you proposed, but we have the same error on orion logs: (curl_easy_perform failed: SSL connect error)

What else could I do?

Comment: In the new scenario (i.e. not using docker), do you get that error when you use nc as receiver, your service or in both cases?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Finally I found the solution in this new scenario: yum update... The container wasn't updated, just the same as the image I launched. After doing an update, it installed the new CA certificates, recognizing letsencrypt as a valid Certificate Authorization.

Thank you very much for your support @fgalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in this new scenario: `yum update` . The container wasn't updated, just the same as the image I launched. After doing an update, it installed the new CA certificates, recognizing letsencrypt as a valid Certificate Authorization. Thank you very much for your support @fgalan